# "Resource not found" trying to add junit tests into sonarqube

Tags: jenkins, junit, sonarqube

I am trying to associate junit test results with SonarQube.

Here is what I have for Sonar Properties:

```
sonar.projectKey=FXX
sonar.projectName=FUTURE_Jason
sonar.projectVersion=12.9.0
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=src
sonar.tests=test-build/junit/classes/
sonar.junit.reportsPath=test-build/junit/reports
```

When executing a Jenkins job associated with SonarQube, I am receiving the following warnings:

```
13:52:12.923 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor
13:52:12.924 INFO  - parsing /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/FUTURE_SONAR_Jason/workspace/test-build/junit/reports

13:52:13.472 WARN  - Resource not found: msc.rc.model.AbstractTrackingUpdateTest
```

In the Jenkins workspace I have the directory test-build and it includes both the reports and classes.

```
$ ll /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/FUTURE_SONAR_Jason/workspace/test-build/junit/classes/msc/rc/model/AbstractTrackingUpdateTest.class
-rwxr-xr-x 1 build build 9590 Dec 14 14:39 /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/FUTURE_SONAR_Jason/workspace/test-build/junit/classes/msc/rc/model/AbstractTrackingUpdateTest.class
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: `sonar.tests=test-build/junit/classes/`
Does this point to compiled class? we point it to test files (.java)

Comment: Thanks Shiva...when I changed this to point to the .java files, the problem is now resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the sonar.tests property to point to the .java files, problem is now resolved.